# How to clean spark history event log with out stopping spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a spark streaming application which is a long running task. The event log is pointed to hdfs location hdfs://spark-history, the application_XXX.inprogress file is being created in it when we start streaming application and size of the file growing up to 70GB. To delete the log file we are stopping spark streaming application and clearing it. 
Is there any way to automate this process with out stopping or restarting application. We have configured the spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true with cleaning interval as 1 day and max Age as 2 days. however it is not cleaning the .inprogress file. we are using spark 1.6.2 version. We are running the spark on yarn and deployed in cluster mode.

Comment: What is retention policy for hdfs log storage ?

Answer (score 3):

This issue you have to do some changes in few configurations, you have to add few changes to your file `yarn-default.xml`. In this file you need to change this row or add this row:

```
yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds=3600
```

This modification will aggregate your files to you, this will allow you to see the data via `yarn logs -applicationId YOUR_APP_ID`

This is the first step. You can see a little about this [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties).

Seccond Step you need to create a file log4j-driver.property and a log4j-executor.property

In this file you can use this example:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling
log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rolling.file=/var/log/spark/${dm.logging.name}.log
log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.com.anjuke.dm=${dm.logging.level}
```

What this rows are saing?

This guy: `log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=50MB` will create just files with 50MB of size. When a log file reach 50MB it will be closed and a new one will start.

The other row that is relevant is this one: `log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=5` this means that you will have a backup history of 5 files of 50MB. During the time this will be deleted when a new files start to show.

After you create this log file you need to send this via spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit
  --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077
  --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j-driver.properties -Ddm.logging.level=DEBUG"
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j-executor.properties -Ddm.logging.name=myapp -Ddm.logging.level=DEBUG"
  ...
```

You can create a log file for your Driver and for your Workers. In the command I'm using two different files but you can use the same. For more details you can see [here](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2015/05/31/spark-streaming-logging-configuration/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we have enabled log aggregation and  yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds=3600. The log is not increasing in executors, it is incresing only in spark history folder which is having spark streaming event logs in json format for resconstruction of history UI  with file a name as application_12XXX_.inprogress

Comment: God! I understood your point. I have to check mine folder of history server. I didn't realize that

Comment: @VamshiMothe Thanks for your Update! We also having the same problem. We have now some history data `.inprogress` with more than 100Gb of data o_0 so I will try to find the solution and update you soon!

Comment: @VamshiMothe have you try these configuration? `spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true` `spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=1d` `spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge=7d`

Comment: yes, we have already enabled but its is not cleaning .inprogress files.

Comment: Well, I have the same problem now. I will try to find the solution

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Hi, do you have any updates, i have e same problem with progress file/

Comment: @user2870704 we didn't find a solution for that with Spark Configuration. When we got an update we will update the answer. Sorry :(

Comment: Has anybody found a solution to this problem. I am running into this issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: @belletian Sorry, I left that project without solving the problem at all. :(

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim I am using spark structured streaming on GCP did you guys find solution for this .inprogress file ?

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. Did anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Same here, no solutions?

Comment: From spark 3.0.0 onwards there is an option to compact spark event logs to reduce their size: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#applying-compaction-on-rolling-event-log-files