# How to deal with growing logs in Spark Structured Streaming application on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, logging, streaming, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

We are running multiple Spark Structured Streaming application. These application are continously running 24*7. We noticed the HDFS disk usgae size is growing.

[hadoop@ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx ~]$ hdfs dfs -du -h /var/log/spark/apps
10.6 G   10.8 G   /var/log/spark/apps/application_1815393722510_0026_1.inprogress
12.1 G   12.3 G   /var/log/spark/apps/application_1815393722510_0028_1.inprogress
9.3 G    9.4 G    /var/log/spark/apps/application_1815393722510_0029_1.inprogress
9.9 G    10 G     /var/log/spark/apps/application_1815393722510_0030_1.inprogress
5.0 G    5.1 G    /var/log/spark/apps/application_1815393722510_0031_1.inprogress
768.0 M  896 M    /var/log/spark/apps/application_1815393722510_0065_1.inprogress
[hadoop@ip-xxx-xxx-x-xxx ~]$

I have enabled spark event logs by the propetry spark.eventLog.enabled=true

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781031/how-to-clean-spark-history-event-log-with-out-stopping-spark-streaming?rq=2

Comment: Tried already, but doesn't seem to be working.